# TransitionDrawable: automatically reverse transition once it completes

Tags: android

I want to highliht newly-added ListView items with a nice effect. I thought that was simple&easy, but I stumpled upon a problem:

I want to play TransitionDrawable animation and once it completes - rewind it. The new item is going to be highlited for a moment, and then it will blend with the rest.

TransitionDrawable has methods for playing animation forward and backward, but none that could be used for synchronization. I expected a possibility to specify a callback for animation completion, something like:

```
 TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground();
 transition.startTransition(500, new TransitionCompleteListener(){
               public void completed()
               { 
                    transition.reverseTransition(500);
               }
       });
```

But nothing like that is supported by TransitionDrawable class.

The problem is: How to play TransitionDrawable animation, and when it finishes - immediately play it backwards? I had an idea of using `Timer` class to delay execution of the backwards part of the animation, but this solution looks a bit too heavy for such a simple thing.

Or maybe I should use something different that TransitionDrawable? I'd like to avoid using  Property Animations, since I want to support older devices (and PA are avaialble since Honeycomb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't actually tried it myself yet, but I'd say what you're aiming for might also be possible with an old fashioned View animation, a [tween](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween) to be precise. In stead of directly manipulating the background drawable (assuming that's what you're currently doing), you could potentially create the same effect by changing the alpha property of a View that has exactly the same dimensions as the row layout. You can then specify both the 'normal' animation and its reverse in a single AnimationSet and have the latter start with a delay based on the first. Alternatively, Animation provides an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) you can hook up to and get notified when the first animation ends, and subsequently start its reverse.

Looking at the source code for TransitionDrawable, I also see some possibilities to extend the current implementation with a custom listener interface. It shouldn't be too hard to actually realise the pattern you illustrate in the code snippet in your question.

I'm a bit short on time right now, so shoot me a comment in case you need any more concrete pointers (e.g. code snippets) - I'll then try to find some time this weekend to help you out.

Comment: Hmm... Using a tween could work if I would set background color of a whole ListView to the color used to hightlight items, and set color of all rows to white. Then, by manipulating alpha value of a specific row, I would achieve highliht effect. but the idea of subclassing TransitionDrawable seems better, more clean and just more "right". I looked at it's source now and it seems quite easy to implement what I need. I'll update my question with a solution when I'll code it, now I need to go back to my Master Thesis (not related to this ofc - it's a hobby project). You win the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
Drawable[] transBack =  new Drawable[] { res.getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_acept_blue ), res.getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_acept )};

ImageView btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resource);
TransitionDrawable transitionAcept = new TransitionDrawable(transBack);
btn.setImageDrawable(transitionAcept);

btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
           TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) btn.getDrawable();
           transition.startTransition(75);
      }break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
           TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) btnAcept.getDrawable();
           transition.reverseTransition(75);
           v.performClick();
      }break;
      default:
       break;
   }
   return true;
}
});
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      //... DO Something here
   }
});
```

The above code implements a TouchListener to handle reverse and forward transition, and a clickListener to handle your actions. That's why in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you call for `v.performClick();` Hope this Help You.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the implementation of TransitionDrawable (actually copied it and modified) to accept a repeatCount parameter which states how many times to make the transition forth and back. See the `RepeatableTransitionDrawable` in the repository below.

I also plan to add more than two drawables support.

https://github.com/mehmet6parmak/CustomDrawables

Answer (score 0):

Try with a Handler ;)

```
final TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) sizesSelectionLayout.getBackground();
int duration = 500;
transition.startTransition(duration);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        transition.reverseTransition(duration);
    }
}, duration);
```

;)

Answer (score -2):

Evaluate using ViewAnimator instead
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html

The in and out animation object attached to the ViewAnimator have an AnimationListener which triggers the event you want to capture

Comment: I may be wrong - but isn't ViewAnimator used to switch between views (like in ViewFlipper, which is it's subclass)?

Comment: yes and my suggestion would be to have two views; one normal and one highlighted. Basically, for your list row xml, you have the ViewAnimator as the outer element and its children are the same as your current list row. Then, when an element is added which you want to have focus, you through code add a new view to the ViewAnimator and start the transition to the view that represents your highlighted state. You set up an event listener and capture the event when it is finished, and you reverse the action.